# How to concatenate an absolute path and relative path with QDir?

Tags: qt, filenames, relative-path, absolute-path, qdir

I have a relative path and absolute path that look something like this:

```
Absolute: /tmp/somedir
Relative: anotherdir/file.txt
```

I would like to concatenate the two (`/tmp/somedir/anotherdir/file.txt`) with [QDir](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html) but I am not quite sure what the proper way of doing that is.

According to the documentation for [`QDir::absoluteFilePath`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#absoluteFilePath):

> "Returns the absolute path name of a file in the directory."

This would be ideal if all I had was a filename, but I have a relative path as well. I looked at some of the other functions on the page, but none of them seemed to be what I was looking for.

What function should I be using?

Answer (score 38):

I think you are looking for [`filePath()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#filePath).

```
QString finalPath = QDir("/tmp/somedir").filePath("anotherdir/file.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

Small addition if the relative file path starts with a dot:

```cpp
QString absoluteDirPath = "/tmp/somedir";
QString relativeFilePath = "./anotherdir/file.txt";

QString incorrectPath = QDir{absoluteDirPath}.filePath(relativeFilePath);
qDebug() << "incorrect path:" << incorrectPath;
QString correctPath = QFileInfo{incorrectPath}.absoluteFilePath(); // removes the .
qDebug() << "correct path:" << correctPath;
```

Output:

```
incorrect path: "/tmp/somedir/./anotherdir/file.txt"
correct path: "/tmp/somedir/anotherdir/file.txt"
```